# Viewing email address of WhatsApp contacts

Tags: email, whatsapp

Can I view the email address of my WhatsApp contacts?

I am unable to view email addresses since the signing up was done using phone number by my contacts.

If the sign up was done by the contact using an email address, then I would have been able to view his/her email address?

Attached WhatsApp contacts example image.

[image][image]!

Comment: Please note that this site is about *recommending software meeting specific requirements,* not about *solving issues with software* you already have. If you intended to ask for software, please see  [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide. Otherwise please check the `/help/ontopic` page of other SE sites to see where your question fits. You could start with [SuperUser](//superuser.com/help/on-topic), for example.

Comment: Thanks.

I got a workaround in WhatsApp. In About Field, i can specify my email address for others to view my contact and send me email at my email address.